# What is the request for getting Twitter Timeline?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I would like to know what is the request for getting Twitter timeline for a user ?

I will prefer getting JSON in output.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the API documentation would not give instructions for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API has changed over time, and I dusted off some code of mine just the other day and updated the call.  What you want is:
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=[username]

Example: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=gutzman

For more information, read the documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply. I have search in the documentation, and i would like to find the same thing for the home timeline for a user.Do you have an example also?